# Child to parent using context API, onClick gets called several times - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Parent Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import List from './components/List/list';
import Context from './Context/productsContext';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    products : [],
    cartProducts:[]
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    console.log("effect");
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/ITEMS").then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(result => this.setState({
      products: result
    }));
  }

  addToCart = (product) => {
    const prod = this.state.products;
    prod.push(product);
    this.setState({
      cartProducts:prod
    })
  }

  render () {
    console.log("PRoducts",this.state)
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{
        products: this.state.products,
        cartProducts:this.state.cartProducts,
        addToCart: (prod) => this.addToCart(prod)
      }}>
      <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <List />
      </div>
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Child Component :

```
import React from 'react';
import Context from '../../Context/productsContext';
import './list.scss';

function List(props) {
  return (
    <div className="main-container">
     <div className="filter-container">
          Hello
     </div>
     <div className="list-container">
     <Context.Consumer>
       {
         value => {
           return value.products.map((v,i) => 
           <div key={i} className="card">
             <img src={v.image} alt={v.name} style={{width:"25%"}} />
             <div className="container">
               <h4>{v.name}</h4>
               <button className="add-button" onClick={() => value.addToCart(v)}>Add To Cart</button>
             </div>       
           </div>

           )
         }

       }
     </Context.Consumer>
     </div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default List;
```

**When I call function addToCart from child using context API, it calls as many time as it has that array length, is there a way to call only once and communicate to parent ?
This is the values I get if I click a button, it's adding all values, but I want to add only one particular to the array on button click.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know for a fact the callback is being invoked multiple times? or is it just the handler logic is adding the value `v` multiple times? Based on your use of array::push (versus method that doesn't mutate state objects) in the `addToCart` handler you've likely other logical bugs as well.

My guess is you probably didn't mean to save a reference to `this.state.products`, mutate it with array::push, and then save the reference back into state under `this.state.cartProducts`.

```
addToCart = (product) => {
  const prod = this.state.products; // <-- saved state reference
  prod.push(product); // <-- mutate state reference!!
  this.setState({
    cartProducts:prod // <-- saved reference to other state, both now equal
  })
}
```

I believe you more likely meant to copy the existing cart contents and add the new product. The following method spreads the existing cart products into a *new* array and appends the specified product at the end. This leaves the `product` array untouched for display in `List`.

```
addToCart = (product) => {
  const { cartProducts } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    cartProducts: [...cartProducts, product],
  })
}
```

Try this and see if the issue resolves.